# Edit Shopware 6 registration form

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware5

I have recently installed shopware 6, just wanted to know how I can customize my login or registration form if I wanted Salutation* to Company Type on registration form how can I change? Please please help me someone how is expert on shopware 6

Answer (score 3):

Shopware 6 comes with many configuration settings for the login and registration out of the box.

In the administration area of your shop go to `Settings ->  Login / Registration` and adjust the settings to fit your needs.

In your case i think you want to activate the `Show selection between company and customer account` setting.

If you need further customization you probably want to install a ready made plugin from the [shopware store](https://store.shopware.com/en/extensions/?p=1&o=12&n=21&shopwareVersion=6.4) or develop your own [custom plugin](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/concepts/extensions/plugins-concept).